# jQuery Each, Iterate from starting element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to start an each loop starting from a certain element instead of all the elements?

e.g. If i wanted to make items above "Item two" red. *(I'm aware there's no need for an each loop to do that, this is just an example case)*

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

Comment: [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Comment: @Andreas: That what the dupe I found says as well. +1 on that comment :-)

Comment: @cebrus The GT selector suggested below will work better for me than slice in this instance. I didn't see your suggestions in my search(likely asking the wrong question). What is the etiquette on asking a "duplicate" question in this instance??? Do I still accept an answer?

Comment: @Cerbrus Didn't knew it was dupe, removed answer as I saw `gt` used in the so dupe answer

Comment: @Novocent Use `$('li:gt(1)')`

Comment: @Novocent: Sure, accept an answer. A question being marked as a dupe doesn't necessarily mean it's a bad question.

Comment: @Tushar should you repost your answer so I can accept it? Sorry folks, a little stack green, I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can check current item index and skip iteration:

```js
$('li').each(function(){
  if( $( this ).index() < 2 ) return true;
  $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have a gold badge in JS, next time, please close as dupe instead of answering...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` property of  `.each` function.

```js
$('li').each(function(index) {
  if (index > 1) {
    $(this).css("color", "red");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var lis = $('ul').children();
console.log($(lis).length);
for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++)
  {
      
      $(lis[i]).css("color", "red");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```